# Producer method for ambiguous dependency not found

Tags: cdi, producer

I am trying to get a producer method to work to resolve an ambiguous dependency. But I just won't recognize the producer method. The other dependencies get resolved without a problem. I already different variations in the code but I always get the same error. This is my log-output:

```
10:17:36,317 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."java_rest_test_war_exploded.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."java_rest_test_war_exploded.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SecondInterface with qualifiers @SecondInterfaceAnnotation
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @SecondInterfaceAnnotation private rest.HelloWorldRest.secondInterface
  at rest.HelloWorldRest.secondInterface(HelloWorldRest.java:0)
WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
  - Managed Bean [class rest.SecondBeanImpl2] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class rest.SecondBeanImpl1] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

This is my code:

```
public interface SecondInterface {
    public String getData();
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class FirstBean {

    public String getName() {
        return "FirstBeanName";
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class SecondBeanImpl1 implements SecondInterface {

    public String getData() {
        return "data: SecondBeanImpl ONE";
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class SecondBeanImpl2 implements SecondInterface {

    public String getData() {
        return "data: SecondBeanImpl TWO";
    }
}

@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface SecondInterfaceAnnotation {
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class SecondBeanProducer {

    @Produces
    @SecondInterfaceAnnotation
    public static SecondInterface getSecondInterface(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return new SecondBeanImpl1();
    }
}


@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldRest {

    @Inject
    FirstBean firstBean;

    @Inject
    @SecondInterfaceAnnotation
    SecondInterface secondInterface;

    @GET
    @Path("/getdata")
    public Response printAppName() throws Exception {
        System.err.println(appName);
        return Response.status(200).entity(secondInterface.getData()).build();
    }
}
```

And my beans.xml in WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

EDIT:

I got it know working by adding scopes:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SecondBeanProducer {

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @SecondInterfaceAnnotation
    public static SecondInterface getSecondInterface(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return new SecondBeanImpl1();
    }
}


@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldRest {

    @Inject
    FirstBean firstBean;

    @Inject
    @ApplicationScoped
    @SecondInterfaceAnnotation
    SecondInterface secondInterface;
```

Comment: Why do you need the `public static SecondInterface getSecondInterface` producer? Are you running any special code in that producer? Or rather the question is: *why don't you apply `@SecondInterfaceAnnotation` to class `SecondBeanImpl1` and get rid of the producer method? Nonetheless, I see that Weld isn't picking up the producer when it lists matching beans, and wonder why it doesn't list it

Comment: Try to set bean-discovery-mode to "all".

Comment: It is preferable always to write/start a unit/deployment test with the Arquillian  Runner. Because you can isolate you Code in this case.

Comment: I also already tried discovery model = all and having the producer method non static but I get the same exception. The reason I want to have a producer method is that I want to control via the producer method which implementation is used.

Comment: Are you sure `HelloWorldRest` can be `@ApplicationScoped` bean? I thought servlets are meant to be `InjectionTarget`s (e.g. you can inject into them, but not use them as full blown beans as CDI does not mandate the lifecycle). I also noticed that your deployment name is `java_rest_test_war_exploded.war` - what does `exploded` mean here? Can it affect CDI bean discovery somehow? Basically, what is your deployment structure?